# affectedbygravity in SceneKit?

Tags: ios8, scenekit

I want to make a floating ball.

In spritekit I do **physicsbody.affectedbygravity=NO**;

But what have I do in **scenekit**?

I tried to set mass to zero, but dynamicbody turns to static: it not moved by gravity, nor by collision. My code is

```
// add ball
SCNNode *ball = [SCNNode node];
ball.geometry = [SCNSphere sphereWithRadius:5];
ball.geometry.firstMaterial.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = YES;
ball.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = @"ball.jpg";
ball.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.contentsTransform = SCNMatrix4MakeScale(2, 1, 1);
ball.geometry.firstMaterial.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapModeMirror;
ball.physicsBody = [SCNPhysicsBody dynamicBody];
ball.physicsBody.restitution = 0.9;
//ball.physicsBody.mass=0; //here makes a ball statical and not moving
ball.physicsBody.allowsResting = YES;
[[scene rootNode] addChildNode:ball];
```

**UPD**  this not helps too - ball falls slowly.

```
- (void)renderer:(id<SCNSceneRenderer>)aRenderer didSimulatePhysicsAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time{

[ball.physicsBody applyForce:SCNVector3Make(0, 9.8, 0) atPosition:SCNVector3Make(0,0,0) impulse:NO]; //this
ball.physicsBody.velocity=SCNVector3Make(0,0,0); //or this
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off gravity by setting scene.physicsWorld.gravity to zero.
However If you want some objects to be affected and some not you need to add a [SCNPhysicsField linearGravityField] and configure the categoryBitMask to make it affect the nodes you want.

Comment: I saw it, but Apple's manual says nothing about bitmask - see https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SCNPhysicsField/linearGravityField ----- so, do you mean I have to set the same bitmask both to "gravitated" model and field's node?

Comment: so, Scenekit field mans are here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNPhysicsField_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNPhysicsField/categoryBitMask

Answer (score 0):

I found partial solution and some fun bug.
This makes ball stay unmovable until collision and "float" after that

```
// .... the same code above in creation
﻿ball.physicsBody.mass=1;
[[scene rootNode] addChildNode:ball];
ball.physicsBody.mass=0; //important right after creating!!! or it become bodyless after changing mass to 1
```

and release it if contact. If you apply up force equal to gravity, it will be floating, slowly falling down. Speed of falling may be damped, of cause.

```
﻿// physics contact delegate
- (void)physicsWorld:(SCNPhysicsWorld *)world didBeginContact:(SCNPhysicsContact *)contact{
if (contact.nodeA.physicsBody.type == SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic && contact.nodeA.physicsBody.mass==0)
    contact.nodeA.physicsBody.mass=1;
else
    if (contact.nodeB.physicsBody.type == SCNPhysicsBodyTypeDynamic && contact.nodeB.physicsBody.mass==0)
        contact.nodeB.physicsBody.mass=1;
}
```